# .Net Core 2 WebAPI returns 405 instead of 401 (oidc)

Tags: .net, .net-core

We have Angular 4 frontend, .ner core 2 WebAPI and external oidc idm system. We managed to have signin / signout flows successfully from WebAPI. After user is signed out, if it now requests any page (by url) which requests WebAPI with [Athorize] attributes, WebAPI returns 405 instead of 401. What is the way to intercept the response in WebAPI and, when user is not authorized, return 401 as frontend side expects it?

Comment: Please provide additional details including configurations that could help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using:

```
.AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
                {                    
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };                  
            })
```